# UIStoryboard load from app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I am trying to load a UIStoryboard from the app delegate .m in this way:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *vc =[storybord instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window addSubview:vc.view];

    return YES;
}
```

What is the problem with this code?? any idea?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
   UIViewController *vc =[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

   // Set root view controller and make windows visible
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   self.window.rootViewController = vc;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
}
```

Try this. I think is missing set root view controller and make windows visible.

Comment: I tested this only with iOS 7 (and maybe that's the reason), but I needed to create the window as well: `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];`

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 4.2 and higher.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    window?.rootViewController = viewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From your code I see UIWindow object is not initialised.

You need to initialise it if you don't mention any Storyboard Name in `App-Info.plist`.

Also, make the Window key and visible. Please change your code as displayed below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *vc =[storybord instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window addSubview:vc.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't work this way now.

In the build settings plist there is add an entry for Main Storyboard (or something like that).  The all you need in the applicationDidFinishLoading is return YES;

If you start a new project with storyboards ticked you can see the exact entry.

When that's in there you don't need to load the initial view as it takes it from the storyboard file (Is Initial View flag).

HTH

Comment: yes, but I have 2 UIStoryboards, and I need to load them in base of the dimensions of the iphone 5/4 screen