# Easy way to override which screen shows up first iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Right now I'm trying **storyboards** out, and I have my `UITableViewController` as my `rootViewController`. Now on some instances if my user is not logged in, I want another `UIViewController` to appear first. I understand I can perform a **segue** to it, but from my understanding the `TableView` will still try to get loaded, which is not what I want unless they supply info on this `UIViewController` that I'm trying to get to appear first (if say a key doesn't exist in `NSUserDefaults`) for example.

So my question is, is there an easy solution I can maybe add to my appDelegate to "**override**" the `rootViewController` from storyboard, or appear before it, then have a button simply on it to dismiss back to that `rootViewController` in storyboard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

- Use a different initial view controller (you can specify this in the storyboard). In that view controller, check if the user is logged in. If they are, just transition directly to the table view controller via a manually triggered segue. If not, display the login screen.
- Subclass UITableViewController. Check for the login in viewDidLoad.  If not, present a modal login view controller.

You probably don't want to do it in the app delegate since that would require you to manually load the storyboard, which means unnecessary code.

Comment: I humbly disagree. This will cause the "login screen" to always be created, even though it's not needed. I would go with manual initialization in app delegate.

Comment: That's a premature optimization.  iOS loads and unloads view controllers all the time.  Why wouldn't we trust it to do the right thing?  Initialization in the app delegate, in fact, over-constrains the OS -- it's forced to load the storyboard at a specific time.  How do we know it hasn't already loaded the storyboard by the time didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called?  In a high-level programming environment -- especially iOS -- it's best not to fight the system.

Comment: You can also argue that the login screen shouldn't handle this logic in it's viewDidLoad. It should be handled "outside" of it, in my opinion. It's more a matter of philosophy than premature optimization.

Comment: But the idea of the storyboard is to have a visual representation of the flow of your program.  The first thing the program needs to do is log the user in;  there's a view controller for that.  The next thing is to show the table; there's another view controller for that.  We can see the flow without looking at any code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice you two, and for the answer Anna - app seems to be flowing great with your implementation! You're my hero!

Answer (score 1):

Really similar to this question: [UIStoryboard load from app delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553621/uistoryboard-load-from-app-delegate)

You should set the Storyboard ID in the Identity section of the View Controller in Interface Builder. Then you can get that screen via

```
UIViewController *viewControllerToShow = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
```

You will end up with something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

       UIViewController *vc = nil;
       if (someKindOfCheck) {
           vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
       }
       else {
           vc =[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
       }

       // Set root view controller and make windows visible
       self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
       self.window.rootViewController = vc;
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Instead of initialize new instance of storyboard, you could aswell use self.window.rootViewController.storyboard if you only have one storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to set your table sections to 0 if the user isn't logged in, for example;

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
NSInteger numberOfSections = 0;
if (userLoggedIn) 
{
  numberOfSections = 1;
}   

return numberOfSections;
}
```

Comment: If I went this route, would you happen to know the best route of displaying text in the middle of the UITableView saying "Not logged in" for example? Would it be best practice to simply have a button hidden then not hidden when this is the case, and vice versa?

Comment: When I have done it I have just added a UILabel in the middle of the view. However as you are going to immediately segue to your other UIViewController, then this may not be necessary, especially if that is a modal view.