# presentViewController:animated:NO briefly shows presenting controller in iOS 8. Alternatives?

Tags: ios, ios8, uikit, presentviewcontroller

It's typical during app startup to create your main UI structure, but during if user is not logged in during app launch, to immediately present a modal intro/login screen above the normal UI.

Normally it has been fine to present the modal UI using `presentViewController:animated:NO`, because the user would see: App Launch Image -> Login UI.

However, on iOS 8, it seems calling `presentViewController` with animated = NO **still** briefly shows the underlying view controller for a frame before presenting the view controller.

Example:

[image]

I don't want to present the login UI first, because when the user logged in I'd be *presenting* the main UI from the login UI, thus keeping the login UI around in the hierarchy indefinitely.

Is there another way I haven't considered? Could storyboards help me here?

Comment: Where in your code are you calling `presentViewController:animated:`?

Comment: Please include the code, and say where you are calling it from.

Comment: Hi @DanielT, I'm calling presentViewController during `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I check for logged in status on application launch, and then either install the login view controller or the main root view controller as the window's root view controller.

When the user logs in or out, the window's root view controller is replaced. This can be animated as well. I find this approach quite clean.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that replacing the root view controller could be animated, using `[UIView transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion]`! This solved the problem for me, although as @anna-dickinson said, you can use storyboards too.

Comment: I use storyboards as well, just not with one set as the main interface in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the problem will go away if you use storyboards and don't programmaticly instantiate your initial or login view controllers. UIKit seems to work best when you just let it do its thing...

Here's how to conditionally bring up the login view controller using a storyboard:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26657778/1442620

Comment: Thanks for this! 100% agree that you shouldn't be fighting UIKit. That said, I don't Apple has decreed that storyboards are required for launching an app, and that _not_ using them is wrong. They are very powerful and useful for a great many apps, and I agree that it could solve my issue here as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your exact usecase is, but in my app the user could be logged out at any moment regardless of what view controller (s)he happens to be in at the time. I need to then present the login screen and give the user a chance to log back in, and put the user right back where (s)he was if login was successful.

What all this means is that I can't make the login view controller the root and stack the other controllers on top of it, because I can't just pop them all off if the user gets logged out.

However, I can save the VC stack and swap out to the login screen, then swap back to the main VC stack when login is successful.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var primaryViewController: UIViewController?
    var loginViewController: UIViewController?

    func userLoggedOut() {
        self.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
    }

    func userLoggedIn() {
        self.window?.rootViewController = primaryViewController
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // other setup code
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as? UIViewController
        primaryViewController = self.window?.rootViewController

        if (!currentlyLoggedIn) {
            userLoggedOut()
        }
        return true
    }
```