# Xcode 6: Storyboards

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I loved Xcode 4 when there was two storyboards, one for the iPhone and one for the iPad. There was only one screen size to which was the 3.5 inch which made the layout so much easier.  Then Xcode 5 came along and it was different because the iPhone storyboard layout changed for the 3.5 inch screen and the 4 inch screen and it was quite difficult to use.  Now Xcode 6 is here and I now only have one Storyboard. I hate it. I cannot get any of my iPhones buttons and labels to line up at all.  iPhone 4 inch and 4.7 is fine, but the 3.5 is all off. I have tried all those tricks of resetting the suggested constraints too.  So my question is, is there any way to have more than one storyboard? I would really like to have one for the iPhone 3.5 inch, another for the iPhone 4.0 inch, another for the 4.7 inch, one for the 5.5 inch and one for the iPad.  I would also like them to all work fine and not interfere with each other and there layout.  I am not worried if I have to do everything about 5 times but I would rater spend more time and get the layout correct.  So if this is possible I would be extremely happy!

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading the storyboard in your AppDelegate.

Described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12553838/866904

Create 2 storyboards and then just load the preferred one in your AppDelegate.